# Using ProjectEuler to learn C, probably a simple mistake

Tags: c

this gives the amount 200003

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int i = 0;
int x = 0, x15 = 0;
     for (i=0; i<1000; i++){
            if (i%3==0 || i%5==0){
                    x += i;
            }
            if (i%15==0){
                    x15 += i;
            }
    }
printf("%d'\n", x-x15);
return 0;
}
```

this gives the amount 233168

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int i = 0;
int x3 = 0, x5 = 0, x15 = 0;

    for (i=0; i<1000; i++){

            if (i%3==0){
                    x3 += i;
            }
            if(i%5==0){
                    x5 += i;
            }
            if (i%15==0){
                    x15 += i;
            }
    }
printf("%d\n", x3+x5-x15);
return 0;
}
```

can anyone explain what's different between the two?  I would expect the two to provide the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple of 15 will be added to both x3 and x5 in the bottom code, so they are counted twice.  In the top version, each is counted only once.

Answer (score 1):

A number can be a multiple of 3 and 5, for example 15

Answer (score 1):

After some simplification, the difference between the two codes is:

```
        if (i%3==0 || i%5==0){
                x += i;
        }
```

and

```
        if (i%3==0){
                x += i;
        }
        if(i%5==0){
                x += i;
        }
```

Obviously, they don't do the same thing. Multiplies of 15 are calculated in the first code once, and in the second one twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (i%3==0 || i%5==0){
            x += i;
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
    if (i%3==0){
            x += i;
    }
    else if(i%5==0){
            x += i;
    }
```

not to

```
    if (i%3==0){
            x += i;
    }
    if(i%5==0){
            x += i;
    }
```